# store emails in textfile one per line

Tags: php

This snippet of code renders a users email when a user enters a page of my site: ...

```
$email=$userprofile->email;
```

... you can echo it like this:

```
<?php echo $email;?>
```

but how would you store it in a text file in a directory or folder of my choosing  with one email per line? thanks

i tried this but it wont work

```
<?php
$file = 'http://mydomain.com/file/email.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $email);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a file to write using a domain name.  You will have to open it on the local file system.  Something like this may work for you:

```
$myFile = "/local/path/to/email.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$email=$userprofile->email."\n";

fwrite($fh, $email);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't file_get_contents() work for reading in the page contents?  I know I have used this for reading authentication responses from external sites....an alternative would be looking at the curl function and output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php [filesystem](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) functions

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
Try this:

```
$fh = fopen('myfile.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fh, $new_email . "\n");
fclose($fh);
```

As Joe mentioned, take heed to the second parameter of fopen. 'a+' will put the pointer at the end of the file. The plus gives you the ability to read from it if needed.

Comment: The key here is "a+" which means append the content on the end (rather than replace it).

Answer (score 0):

First, you cant use an url as file (really you can, but you need to have it enabled in php).
So, let's say that you want to store the emails in a local file:

```
$file = "myfile.txt"
```

file_put_contents() will overwrite the file if it exist, so you need to create a list of emails in a variable, and finally write it to a file:

```
[in an emails loop]
$my_list += $email . '\n'
```

and finally:

```
file_put_contents($file, $emails_list);
```

Comment: i have php ini access..how would I use a url as a file then?

Comment: The above answer are right, but you will open, write and close the file for each email, it's much better to do only one open, write and close, just like the file_put_contents(). To use an URL, you can do $handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w"); to open the external file.